# The for loop in React showing ESLint error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

The for loop inside the objToQueryString function showing me the error

> ESLint: The body of a for-in should be wrapped in an if statement to filter unwanted properties from the prototype.(guard-for-in)

```
const objToQueryString = obj => {
  const keyValuePairs = [];
  for (const key in obj) {
    keyValuePairs.push(
      `${encodeURIComponent(key)}${encodeURIComponent(
        `: "`
      )}${encodeURIComponent(obj[key])}`
    );
  }
  return `${encodeURIComponent(`{`)}${keyValuePairs.join(
    encodeURIComponent(`", `)
  )}${encodeURIComponent(`" }`)}`;
};
```

And adding this: `// eslint-disable-next-line guard-for-in` is not working

Comment: Maybe instead of going straight to the "disable-the-rule" technique, you instead [learn to understand the error/warning and fix the underlying issue](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/guard-for-in). In this case, it's complaining because most people use `for...in` incorrectly. Indeed this code would be better done using ``const keyValuePairs = Object.entries(obj).map(([key, value]) => encodeURIComponent(`${key}: "${value}"`);``....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your push statement with

```
const objToQueryString = (obj) => {
  const keyValuePairs = [];
  for (const key in obj) {
    if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, key)) {
      keyValuePairs.push(
        `${encodeURIComponent(key)}${encodeURIComponent(
          ': "',
        )}${encodeURIComponent(obj[key])}`,
      );
    }
  }
  return `${encodeURIComponent('{')}${keyValuePairs.join(
    encodeURIComponent('", '),
  )}${encodeURIComponent('" }')}`;
};
```

More on the rule details and explanation [here](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/guard-for-in)